# How do I correctly hide a button and show it after my BackgroundWorker does something?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Put `button.Visible = false` into my form's initializer and put `button.Visible = true` to the end of my backgroundWorkers's DoWork event.
   This causes the program to freeze after the BackgroundWorker does its work.
   I don't understand why.
2. Put `button.Visible = false` into my form's initializer and put `button.Visible = true` after my `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` call.
   This doesn't work correctly because it displays the button right after the BackgroundWorker starts its work.
   I do understand why this is happening.
3. Put `button.Visible = false` and `doneEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false)` into my form's initializer, then put `doneEvent.WaitOne()` and `button.Visible = true` after my `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()` call.
   This way, everything works fine *except* that the ProgressBar I have in my form stops working correctly (it doesn't show progress until all the work is finished).
   I might have an intuitive idea on why this is happening, but I don't really understand it and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call any method/property on your button while your code runs inside the DoWork event because this code is in a different thread than the thread where the button has been created.
The [BackgroundWorkwer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) use a well defined set of events to handle situations where you need to update your interface and you should use these events for that task.

For example you could set the property `WorkerReportsProgress` to true, subscribe to the event `ProgressChanged` and call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(...);` inside the DoWork event to update your interface while your background work progress.

In your case probably you need to subscribe to the event `RunWorkerCompleted` and show your button in that event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        button.Visible = true; 
    }
}
```

In the link to the MSDN page for BackgroundWorker there is a sample that demonstrate how to update a progress bar while the DoWork event runs a complex task.

Comment: Isn't RunWorkerCompleted also executed in the thread of the worker? (or an arbitrary other thread)? Shouldn't he be doing also Invoke-check?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon a picture worths thousand words http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_w6MdnnxFDk/UBc-c5JUBDI/AAAAAAAAAio/2mLQT5K72co/s1600/Pic03.jpg